# Sencha: Set Dataview XTemplate when created Dynamically

Tags: extjs, view, field

I have some data that I'm getting from the server that depending on the situation may bring different fields, so what I have is this:

```
  //This is the way i'm attaching the newly created template to the view
  //Still no success
  function processDataMethod(response){
      //some processing here...
      var details = Ext.widget('details');
      details.config.itemTpl = new Ext.XTemplate(tplFields);
  }

  Ext.Ajax.request({
                url: '...',
                ...,
                success: function (response, request) {

                    var combinedData = processDataMethod(response);
                    operation.setResultSet(Ext.create('Ext.data.ResultSet', {
                        records: combinedData,
                        total: combinedData.length
                    }));

                    operation.setSuccessful();
                    operation.setCompleted();


                    if (typeof callback == "function") {
                        callback.call(scope || that, operation);

                        currentList.up().push(Ext.widget('details'));
                    }
                }
            });
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Could you post some sample code of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: You are creating a form I assume? Of which the fields are dynamic? What template are you talking about? Are these custom fields which have their own template? Sample code would clarify a lot.

Comment: I edited the post and putted some code, i managed to create the XTemplate succesfully but i'm not being able to bind the view & template :S

Comment: I can't think of an xtype called "details". What kind of component is this? Can you show the source of this too?

Comment: In general: if you use Ext.widget to create an instance of a component, you can/need to pass the options (including the template) as a second argument. In your case: `Ext.widget('details', {itemTpl: yourTemplate});` where `var yourTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate(tplFields);`. Put this yourTemplate variable in a more general scope to both functions if you use it in multiple places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a distinction between a number of things:

- `currentList.up()` returns a DOM element (Ext.dom.Element). This has no method `push()`.
- With `Ext.widget('details', config);` you can pass a config like `{itemTpl: yourTemplate, data: yourData}` to create an instance with a custom template and custom data.
- To update your component after creation you can always do `someWidget.update(data);`.
- A component can be rendered to an HTML element with the `renderTo` option.
- A component can be appended to existing components in different ways and you can update the whole layout or parts of it in different ways. This is unnecessary if you are rendering to an HTML element.

Does that help you find your problem?

Comment: Well done smhg!! I was failing in this:
I created an instance of the view with Ext.widget and after that i was pushing another instance of Ext.widget instead of the one i created earlier... Thanks pal!!